# How to set grid in CSS correctly for mobile-friendly view? (Python Dash project)

Tags: python, css, dashboard, plotly-dash

I have been working on this simple dashboard which can be viewed [using this link](https://covid19-visualisation-seb.herokuapp.com/). The source code [is here](https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/Covid19-visualisation) and the CSS file which is where the problem lies [is here](https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/Covid19-visualisation/blob/master/assets/s1.css). I used grid layout, not sure if it's appropriate for this project, but I chose it becuase I wanted to get some experience with it. My current goal is to make it mobile friendly. I used `@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)` to transform the layout for mobile view. It works when I shrink the page on my pc but when I test it on mobile view it doesn't work (I tried using different `max-width` values such as 400px or 600x and it didn't work. How do I Fix that?

Comment: maybe get some existing CSS framework like `Bootstrap` and see how they do this. Maybe problem is not `@media` but because you don't have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I solved it by adding this tag. Had to find out how to add this meta tag to python Dash. this is the code:

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                 meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                             'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.2, minimum-scale=0.5,'}]
                )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding meta tag to `app = dash.Dash(__name__)`, looks like this:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,
            meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                        'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.2, minimum-scale=0.5,'}]
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

As for me all problem is because you don't use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If I test your page in `Firefox` using `Ctrl+Shift+M` to test page with different sizes then it shows very small images and fonts but if I add `viewport` then it looks correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to add this line of code using python Dash elements?